# how to get all the permissions on facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

in some applications, I see "Access my data any time" when I give the permissions to the iphone application, how can i do that with facebook-ios-sdk ?

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_likes", 
                                @"read_stream",
                                @"user_birthday",
                                nil];
        [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
```

In my code I wrote that but I have to leave the one to one when I want to have all permissions

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That permission scope is called `offline_access`.

Answer (score 0):

the offline_access will no longer exists